# Gravitational effect of charged masses held apart by a rod?

Tags: general-relativity, newtonian-gravity

Imagine two oppositely electrically charged masses held apart by a rigid rod of negligible mass.

At some distance the gravitational field due to this system is proportional to the sum of the masses + the pressure in the rod - the pressure due to the electrical attraction of the opposite charges.

The pressures cancel so that the gravitational field just depends on the masses.

Is this right?

If the charged masses slip off the ends of the rod would the gravitational field due to the system decrease as there is no longer any positive pressure in the rod to balance the negative pressure of the electrical attraction?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking? Are you asking us to calculate the spacetime curvature with and without the rod present? If so that's a formidable challenge. If you're just asking whether the electrostatic repulsion could be equal to the gravitational attraction then yes it can.

Comment: I'm asking if the gravitational mass of the system decreases if the pressure in the rod holding the oppositely charged masses apart disappears.

Comment: I'm pretty certain that the gravity is greater with the rod present, because the pressure in the rod appears on the leading diagonal in the stress energy tensor. However I don't know enough GR to make this quantitative.

Answer (score 1):

This is a poorly posed question in that if you have a rod of negligible mass, it will not support any physical pressure due to the physical contact of the masses. The pressure in the stress energy tensor assumes a massive body, thus allowing the change in density to contribute to the gravitational field. If the pressure were due to some massless force (such as pressure from photons), the gravitational field would not change once the source providing the pressure were removed. That said, if I understand the gist of your question, what you are asking is "Can an electromagnetic force create more gravitational force than was previously there?" The answer is, although it cant add more energy than was previously there, it can redistribute it.  Thus, the electromagnetic force can cause the mass distribution to relocate, increasing the local field strength at the cost of a decreased non-local strength.